# Why I could not get albums from my facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the albums and photos from facebook. I use the below code but the result is always empty array?

```
$albums = $facebook->api('/logudotcom/albums');

// to print
show_output ($albums);

foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
{
    // get all photos for album
    $photos = $facebook->api("/{$album['id']}/photos");
    foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
    {
            echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}' />", "<br />";
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token you're using needs the `user_photos` permission to access your photos via the API - have you granted your app that permission? Check with a call to `/me/permissions/`

Comment: i got reply like this, [installed] => 1
                    [bookmarked] => 1

Comment: So, no, you don't have permission to access the user's photos - see these two documents: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: so, do i need to set permission to allow by the user? please help